# I CAN'T SEE "YAMMER FOR SHAREPOINT" in my SharePoint Store

Tags: sharepoint, yammer

I'm configuring apps for SharePoint to integrate Yammer with my OnPremises SharePoint Farm.
Everything's working fine! but when I type "Yammer for SharePoint" in the "Find an app" input, i can't see the Yammer App in the search results.

[Yammer app for SharePoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5lsQ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a suitable question for Stack Overflow. The product you are looking for has been [discontinued](http://ericoverfield.com/sharepoint-yammer-app-and-webpart-end-of-life-announced/). See the [Yammer Embed](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/embed) documentation for an alternative.